# Телеграм бот не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Я пишу телеграм бота и столкнулся с такой проблемой что бот на одно сообщение не реагирует.

```
@client.message_handler(commands = ['go', 'start'])
def start(message):
    markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item_money = types.KeyboardButton('Купить валюту ')
    item_contacts = types.KeyboardButton('Контакты ')

    markup_reply.add(item_money, item_contacts)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я реселлер валюты на серверах CRMP, SAMP, MTA',
        reply_markup = markup_reply
        )


@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def project(message):
    if message.text == 'Купить валюту ':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_province = types.KeyboardButton(' MTA PROVINCE')
        item_radmir = types.KeyboardButton('⚠️Radmir CRMP')
        item_arizona = types.KeyboardButton(' Arizona SAMP')

        markup_reply.add(item_province, item_radmir, item_arizona)
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Выберите проект',
        reply_markup = markup_reply
        )
    elif message.text == 'Контакты ':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, f'VK - vk.com/lendoroff\n\nTelegram - @lendoroff')


@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text1'])
def server(message):
    if message.text == ' MTA PROVINCE':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_p6 = types.KeyboardButton(' 6 сервер')

        markup_reply.add(item_p6)
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Выберите сервер',
        reply_markup = markup_reply
        )
    elif message.text == '⚠️Radmir CRMP':
        markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
        item_r1 = types.KeyboardButton(' 1 сервер')
        item_r2 = types.KeyboardButton(' 2 сервер')
        item_r3 = types.KeyboardButton(' 3 сервер')
        item_r4 = types.KeyboardButton(' 4 сервер')
        item_r5 = types.KeyboardButton(' 5 сервер')
        item_r6 = types.KeyboardButton(' 6 сервер')

        markup_reply.add(item_r1, item_r2, item_r3, item_r4, item_r5, item_r6)
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Выберите сервер',
        reply_markup = markup_reply
        )
```

вот этот кусок кода. скрин

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`content_types = ['text1']` не будет работать, т.к. не существует такого типа.

`if message.text == ' MTA PROVINCE':` требуется добавить в `def project(message):`

Comment: `elif message.text == ' MTA PROVINCE':`